# Loading OpenSSH certificate into ssh-agent without the private key

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I'm storing my ssh keys on a yubikey and hence I don't have any private key file on disk. This gives me a problem when I'm also using OpenSSH Certificates to authenticate. If I would like to bring the certificate with me using the ssh-agent I need to add it to the agent some how.

This is done automatically if I have a private key called priv and a cert called priv-cert.pub. But since I don't have a file I cant find a way to add the certificate file to the agent.

Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

It seems there is no support for this, I found this feature request: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2472

Answer (score 0):

Yubikey documentation mentions that you can add certificates to the `ssh-agent` here https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/SSH_user_certificates.html

Comment: No it does not. You can add pkcs11 providers but you cannot add certificate files without a corresponding key file on disk. There is a ticket in OpenSSH Bugzilla about it. https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2472

Answer (score 0):

## ssh with Certificates and Hardware Token

This Q might be quite old but hardware auth is getting more common nowadays. The following should work with different hardware keys, as long as the private key is provided by an `ssh-agent` or a substitute like `gpg-agent`.

### TL;DR

Just provide your *public key* file in the `-i` parameter of the `ssh` command:

```bash
ssh -o CertificateFile=yubikey-cert.pub -i yubikey.pub user@example.com
```

### Step by step

This guide has been tested with ssh version:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

It is assumed that the private key has been created on the hardware token. There's absolutely no way to retrieve the private key from the token and store it in a file. The key is accessible only by a software driver that emulates an `ssh-agent` and provides the usual `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. For using the key this driver communicates with the hardware token and any use of the key happens on the token's microcontroller.

#### Get the Public Key

The public key of the token's private key is needed. The *key's hash* can be seen by:

```bash
ssh-add -l
```

Output:

```
4096 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cardno:000000000000 (RSA)
```

The *public key* can be retrieved and stored in a file:

```bash
ssh-add -L > yubikey.pub
```

Output:

```bash
cat yubikey.pub
ssh-rsa AAA.........XXX== cardno:000000000000
```

#### Sign the Public Key

Now the public key can be signed with the *Certificate Authorities* private key, to create a certificate:

```bash
ssh-keygen -s ca.key -I "keyID" -n user -z 4711 yubikey.pub
```

This generates the certificate file `yubikey-cert.pub`. Of course the proper *keyID* and *serial* (`-z` parameter) should be provided.

#### Use the Certificate

The certificate can now be used directly in the `ssh` command. Without relying on the implicit mechanism, key and cert can be passed to `ssh` on the command line. The *private key* must of course be available in the `ssh-agent`.

```bash
ssh -o CertificateFile=yubikey-cert.pub -i yubikey.pub user@example.com
```

For troubleshooting the `-v` switch of ssh can be used to get more details about which key and cert is used:

```bash
ssh -v -o CertificateFile=yubikey-cert.pub -i yubikey.pub user@example.com
```

Output (truncated for brevity):

```
...
debug1: Will attempt key: yubikey-cert.pub RSA-CERT SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: yubikey.pub RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: ...
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: yubikey-cert.pub RSA-CERT SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: yubikey-cert.pub RSA-CERT SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
...
```

A full tutorial of ssh certificates is out of scope of this answer. More information can be found e.g. at the [OpenhSSH Cookbook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Certificate-based_Authentication).

Comment: This works for `ssh` but not when signing things with `ssh-keygen -Y` because it is not possible to supply the `CertificateFile` option with `-O`. `ssh-agent` simply answers with `process_sign_request2: RSA-CERT key not found` because `ssh-add` loaded the private key without a certificate.